# How does Delores get off her loop to leave home and meet William?

Tags: westworld-2016

In the episode entitled "Stray", we see Delores struggle to shoot the man who dragged her into the barn and then ride off and later stumble into Williams' arms. But in the process of struggling with the gun (because she would never hurt a living thing) we see her flashback to the image of the Man in Black.
Warning: the following spoiler is for a later episode than the one referenced.

> That seems impossible since the MiB is an older William.

Comment: You need to watch Westworld *very* carefully for these sorts of answers, because you are regularly seeing the cause and effect of two different time periods, usually interspersed in such a way that the cause and effect you see are actually in the different time periods (Delores struggles with the gun in the later timeline and rides off, Delores stumbles into young Williams arms in the earlier timeline for a different reason).

Comment: I always thought she was remembering/reliving her adventure with William triggered by current events, even physically traveling to those locations and retracing her steps. It has been mentioned that their memories are as real as reality.

Comment: Fricking spoilers dude! I read this question because I'd seen the episode where she meets William but have not seen the episode where your last sentence is revealed.

Comment: I need too add spoilers for seasons that are already a year old? Especially puzzling is that the entire question revolves around the content of what is now spoiler-formatted.I always assumed that persons would seen the series if they were looking at these questions. It's not as though I were asking about a reveal in a current season.

Comment: You don't "need" to but it's polite. I'd guess a lot of people are just watching S1 now or even waiting for S2 before they start.

Comment: My question came up as I was watching for the third time.

Comment: @Moo: Is there a specific schene that portrays the trigger for Delores leaving home and stumbling into William's arms? (There is a scene where her new father asks a question and she then does literally "hurt a fly", which I wondered if it were designed to show us that her inhibitions had been adjusted.)

Answer (score 1):

**Spoiler from Seasons 1 and 2 ahead**

> How does Delores get off her loop to leave home and meet William?

In the third episode of the Season 2, Dolores meets her father

> in the Confederados fort, where she is starting a war between hosts and humans.

She explains that all started when she ran away from the farm because he told her to run away. I didn't locate the exact scene in season 1 but we can assume it is when he became insane after seeing the real world photos.

It seems so far (*) her path and William's one crossed by luck (versus destiny or programmed encountered). At least, William believes it. In one of the last scene of season 1, a young William meets a Dolores whose memory of the adventure together has been erased and is starting a new loop in Sweetwater. He tells her that encountering her was lucky and gave him his purpose in life.

> the process of struggling with the gun (because she would never hurt a living thing) we see her flashback to the image of the Man in Black.

As @Moo pointed out in the comments, two different timelines overlap: the "present" where the Man in Black is using the host to find the center of the maze, and the past timeline where William is having his first trip into West World. They are about 30 years apart.

1. In the "William timeline", the farm is attacked by hosts and is made to run away by her father's words. She has no gun at that time. She then meets William and Logan, and their adventure in Pariah and other places.
2. The "Man in Black timeline", where she is attacked by the Man in Black one more time. I think the Man in Black attacks her to trigger the same behavior than in the "William timeline", that is run away and leading him to the center of the maze. She has a gun in that scene (put in the ground by Bernard under Ford's command).

(*) I watched only until Season 2 episode 3 so far, and we know that, with Ford, nothing is really random.

Comment: I tried to answer as I saw no one ahas answered this question after one year. I reckon that I don't fully understand the reveries/Ford's scheme, so comments are welcome.

Comment: Isn't this just one single timeline?